# Unable to pass Cookies via AJAX call in headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have tried to follow many of the StackOverflow answers, but have not been able to fix this, thus I am creating another question here.

I am trying to call a REST API that requires us to pass a token in a cookie. The API works perfectly fine on Postman. But when try to replicate it from a web page, issues start coming.

So, I have created a simple HTML page with a button that calls a JavaScript method, this method performs an AJAX POST request and passes the cookie as a header.

1. First I started getting CORS errors, so I created a proxy server by using [local-cors-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy)
2. Still I was unable to pass anything in the headers, so I added `--credentials` to the `lcp` command as per the [local-cors-proxy documentation here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy#options)
3. Now I am able to pass the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` as a header, but still not able to pass it as a cookie.

I have also used `document.cookie = "XSRF-TOKEN=3b963005-754b-47e0-b0b6-1289fcf36b00";` to set the cookie, yet it is not passed while making the AJAX request.

Chrome console shows an error while setting the header "cookie".

[image: Chrome error: Refused to set unsafe Header "cookie"]

Below I have added the Request being made via AJAX.

```
var authReq = {
    "url": "http://localhost:8010/proxy/api/security/authenticate",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
        "cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=12345678-abcd-wxyz-1234-1234567890ab",
        "X-XSRF-TOKEN": "12345678-abcd-wxyz-1234-1234567890ab",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     },
     "data": {
         "idToken": "idToken",
         "accessToken": "accessToken"
     },
     crossDomain: true,
     xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
     }
};
```

Comment: Do you need to send header auth or cookie? You need to decide.

Comment: @hamaronooo The api needs me to send the token both as a header as well as a cookie, I have achieved the first part of sending it as a header but cannot send it as a cookie

Comment: Browsers won't let you set a header named `Cookie`; see https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header. Instead, browsers automatically attach cookies to requests when certain conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: @jub0bs I have used `document.cookie` to set the cookie, and can see the same in the Application tab of the console on chrome. Yet the cookies are not passed even when i remove the `Cookie` header

Comment: Whether a cookie will get attached to a request depends on many things, including how the cookie was set. How do you set the cookie in question, on which Web origin, and to which Web origin are you sending the request?

Comment: @jub0bs, since I am working on localhost, `document.cookie` sets the domain as localhost, and the user management API that is being accessed is on an intranet domain, uat-usermanagement.com

Comment: Well, no browser will ever attach a cookie associated to `localhost` to a request sent to another domain like `example.com`. That's just not how cookies work.

Comment: @jub0bs Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252153/discussion-between-basil-victor-and-jub0bs).

Comment: No, I don't have time for synchronous interaction, sorry.

Comment: Allright @jub0bs, but I just wanted to share that I am able to perform this API request on Angular without any issue, so wanted to know whats going wrong in the jquery way

Answer (score 0):

So first of all try to simply set cookie in browser, then don't pass it in fetch header, browser will do it automatically.

You can't manipulate cookies manually in either `XMLHttpRequest` nor `fetch()`. The browser handles cookies automatically.

According to [this answer](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/349#issuecomment-225677823).

*P.S. Interesting thing*
Note that according to [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) if a user agent or browser sends multiple cookies, it will put them in a single field delimited by semicolons: Cookie: name1=value1; name2=value2;